# Error when install min.io with reactjs >18 and webpack > 5.xx

Tags: reactjs, webpack, minio

List err:

- Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in '..\node_modules\sax\lib'
- Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in '..\node_modules\cipher-base'
- Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in '..\node_modules\json-stream\lib'
- Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in '..\node_modules\mime-types'
- Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in '..\node_modules\minio\dist\main'
- Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '..\node_modules\minio\dist\main'
- Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '..\node_modules\mkdirp'
- Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in '..\node_modules\minio\dist\main'
- Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'http' in '..\node_modules\minio\dist\main'
- Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in '..\node_modules\mkdirp'
- Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'https' in '..\node_modules\minio\dist\main'
- Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in '..\node_modules\minio\dist\main'
- Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in '..\node_modules\xml\lib'
- Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'timers' in '..\node_modules\xml2js\lib'

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/To6z2.png)

Answer (score 0):

the only solution now is to resolve the dependencies manually :

check this out
https://github.com/minio/minio-js/issues/1053